# display qrcode in html without saving it in php

Tags: php, laravel, image, qr-code

my project is on laravel 5.4

I use [qr code package](https://github.com/endroid/qr-code) to generate qr code. my goal is to make the qr code, then send it to view(which will be converted to pdf). is it possible to send this code without saving it in file?

```
//here I generate qr code
$qrCode = new QrCode($qrCodeString);
$qrCode->setSize(200);
$qrCode->setWriterByName('png');
$qrCode->setEncoding('UTF-8');

// then I create pdf from html, where I want to attach qr code
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf-view', [
   'username' => $username,
   'qrcode' => $qrCode
]);
```

for now its like a raw file, if I try to print it in html, it looks like

```
b"""
ëPNG\r\n
\x1A\n
\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00▄\x00\x00\x00▄\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00ö8XÍ\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0E─\x00\x00\x0E─\x01ò+\x0E\e\x00\x00\x06IIDATx£Ý¦█v┌0\x10Fßðı¸\x7FÕ¶ûài¡Nµ░%÷wMl\x03\x7FóîÄÅ´´´/ëõÎ¶\x03H»\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp~▀¥Ô±x4<Ã?\x04\x06B▀>¾╦uV^\x13╗‗è¼'\³vb?Uõ÷Ò‗/Ñp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp¯½oÜ¼·w±Ô+W^)f│«3Ì\x19Ê \x18╩ó¨ÛØƒ°§-\x00´^ÎI┤‗H)\x02¤c¾-\x1CC)\x1CC)\x1CC)££Ûø÷¤§è┼g╬¬~Â½Ü\x07┐Ë²║äVÌs°sIÖ┤qòò╚Ê¸╬a¾-\x1CC)\x1CC)\x1CC)£²\n
Ø±J?kñ;v»Â╣±â÷\vÕÄbÖÏ«\x17)ï═Àp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp,tfäïÿO¿~÷\vel╬vÓ\x05Ú?¿E6▀┬1ö┬1ö┬1ö┬┘»ðëòƒëEkýRûGÙrBy­'Ì╣ë^l▓Eæ┴´Èµ[8åR8åR8åR8┴Bç?\x02K[»\x1D█Q¡│┌Ó|º¹u\t¢òÁ;\x19Ý5+Pøýº░¨\x16Äí\x14Äí\x14Äí\x14╬!à╬Ä╗à´°╠=¯CI\eÎN▄½<Õ¡┼vBâ\x1FD7╦µ[8åR8åR8åR8├þ}´8Dv;B\r|\x17▒g.z═¡C║ä«RéRZ5\x17EÖVÚ\x07Ï|\vÃP\n
ÃP\n
ÃP\n
g©ð®¹\x1F£?Ë;K¦B°®Ð¨G¦¨Y▒Û2Ñïí¡¾bQ¾╗╚·®Ïu~■\x19┌|\vÃP\n
ÃP\n
ÃP\n
gxý;v╗║¬╣s\;÷.ã7Ø\v▄ï;÷M\eôm~×@©c╗╗w÷r\x14▒¨\x16Äí\x14Äí\x14Äí\x14Naí\x03ƒ[║°x│u+Ýºz\x04CÖÁ;wÐ.▀Ñe#\x7FÊF█ÌÚE\x1Fà═Àp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑpX{×ù×é¦6>■╔÷[¸\x1D¹‗Ä<¾+<¸Ô\x13~\x01l¥àc(àc(àc(à3╣¯\e8·\tÙ¼AÎ─{Ñê}âÀosxý¹÷╩u_g8\x01gÈ┐õwa¾-\x1CC)\x1CC)\x1CC)££Û;▒Äµ¤ú¯\x1CgÅ¦}¸[\x17×8Vwµ§ÓhxþÌÚ┤ò‗oU³·┘|\vÃP\n
ÃP\n
ÃP\n
'©Ù\x1AyÉ*WVo@¦6Ì1Y¾þ+µßO¯║Â‗\x1AÓ<¾öq ╬>ì+Ó¨k¤l¥àc(àc(àc(àËÀ¯╗tÀ­N³u▀)ƒO©Î\x05┤þ9ÝïI┴\x1F}µ?aÇ═Àp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑpÊ\n
\x1D~MzU7■[g÷ä¶ö+W¡¹«C;\x7F<å÷\v┘ÂÜ>|»g6▀┬1ö┬1ö┬1ö┬┴Ø8vã©vý▄p°jqð║´ÀhÙÁÙNË\x1E4~ÌwÓ:ü\x17\┘|\vÃP\n
ÃP\n
ÃP\n
þÐv£Q®║═┤f═>sþÓõ│╚«ku5Ó\x15­k(:Ù<▒ÃáÞ╗p¦À>ùí\x14Äí\x14Äí\x14╬­$▀µ#¢è¯ı6Ñw|è;w¦wl ┤½Ê\n
=%(Ø{òÎØÇFø\x06\x7F╦µ[8åR8åR8åR8}{×7\x0F\x18\x1E░Ùx°\x1C7┌( fÙ¥\x07\v├╬¾¥\x13Gì?a§║═Àp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\n
¤¹N\x1Ci\f\9v»ö\x7FÝKÎt{Ì¸\x1EÛfDÎòƒÒþ»e¢ÁèÌ\x00øoß\x18Jß\x18Jß\x18JßÓv]#▀Þo¸¬Ùg¿CÌ´²Ï▒´┴¡¸hUsÍ¾©¯[ƒ╦P\n
ÃP\n
ÃP\n
þÉu▀ØW×¢u¦<sN @N(Ã¹Dh\v\x00Vý°╠+~Ìºa¾-\x1CC)\x1CC)\x1CC)£\x13&¨~U×nÂ¦¯P\x07êýy\x1E3¥\x1E Ñ┌¦tãxÍF\f==\x066▀┬1ö┬1ö┬1ö┬\t¯║ÍiÂ■\r╠ð\x0E´ûV¶<ïÀ«½D;÷<\x07Ôƒ¸¦yû┘¯l¥àc(àc(àc(àsHí\x13É8C;kÄs¦\x08■¼ª=¤ï║iÇ3$hu}█\x08~Íu\x02Oh¾-\x1CC)\x1CC)\x1CC)£┬=¤Wðãm\x17oÀØ¢Ì┼þv\t¢5x×\x17|'┤N6▀┬1ö┬1ö┬1ö┬9ñð┘±┐¹\x03F║ï\x1EµÉP^¦v\x12┼Vpg=╠x]O>7▄µ[8åR8åR8åR8Ã\x16:/\x16 æþƒ¸\x1D~\x00°òƒ}J(iã¸á╦R±╦f¾-\x1CC)\x1CC)\x1CC)£c\vØö\n
 ▒f¤:)îÂ\x07{Ós«Z¸²┐À®vã\x17\x1CPzÍ█È.p6▀┬1ö┬1ö┬1ö┬\t\x16:Òú[/h¤3¿nÃ§Â\x0F¨Ï.í\x14ë3ã\x033ßÅ¨Msµ╣Âg(àc(àc(à¾8`¿Mç±/Ñp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp\fÑp■\x00UaA╔ ├HÖ\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND«B`é
"""
```

if I save file first and then just indicate the url of file in html (like `<img src='pathToFile'`), it works fine, but is there way to show this file in view without saving it?

Comment: Make the content a base46 string and echo it in an img tag?!

Comment: yeah, I already tried it, but I was printing with `base64decode`, now remove this functions and it works. thank you, please write your comment as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the content of the image to an `base64` string and then put it in the `src` of the `img` tag. For example somehow like this:

```
$base64Image = 'R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==';
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $base64Image . '" />';
```